# Seeing % of totals on Dashboard using Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I created a dashboard in Tableau that is filtering by the state. When i click on a specific state I want to see the states revenue and other metrics which I was able to do.

Now I also want to see the States % of revenue compared to all states when I apply the filter on the Dashboard.

Hope this makes sense and was wondering if it was possible.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect the end result to be?

Answer (score 0):

Í am not aware of how exaclty your data is or how you have shaped up your dashboard but you can try using table calculations.Here is a screenshot of options in a table calculation:[image]

You can choose Percent of total and according to your data specify if the percent should be calculated across table,pane etc.

Next create a calculated field which looks something like this:

> lookup(min(state),0)

Use this calculated field as a filter instead of the orginal dimension.
The percent of total will always calculate across all data even if you select only one state.

For further clarity refer to: http://www.theinformationlab.co.uk/2013/01/14/maintaining-percent-of-total-whilst-filtering/
It mentions other ways to achieve this too...

Comment: Right click on a field and select add table calculation                      additiona link for reference:http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/using-table-calculations

Comment: Nice start, but it doesn't cover the filters part, which is very trick to combine with table calculations

Comment: @Inox edited my answer to reflect the filter issue.Tested the lookup function on the superstore database to get % of total for region and its working well when i use this as a filter for regions

Comment: Good one. Using table calculations in filters is a valuable trick. Now only the op can say if that works. Honestly I didn't quite understand what he is trying to do